# Unable to download file on Client Location C# Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I am trying to download a zip file and at the same extracting and running unzipped content however when code is executed, zip file is extracting at server location and also content is running there. Below is the code that I have written. I have hosted the code on in local network. I have even tried Write() instead of TransmitFile()

```
try
{
    string launchPresentationPath = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);
    string exeFolder = launchPresentationPath.Replace("/Launch_Presentation.exe", "");

    string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/Uploads/" + exeFolder + ".zip"; //+ Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument);

    string userRoot = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
    string str1 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);

    downloadFolder = Path.Combine(userRoot, "Downloads");

    string strAttach = "attachment; filename=" + exeFolder.Substring(exeFolder.IndexOf('/') + 1) + ".zip";

    System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
    if (file.Exists)
    {
        HttpResponse res = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        res.Clear();
        res.AppendHeader("content-disposition", strAttach);
        res.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        res.TransmitFile(path);

        using (ZipFile zip2 = ZipFile.Read(path))
        {
            zip2.ExtractAll(downloadFolder, Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.DoNotOverwrite);
        }

        DirectoryInfo f = new DirectoryInfo(downloadFolder + "\\" + exeFolder.Substring(exeFolder.IndexOf('/') + 1));
        FileInfo[] a = f.GetFiles();
        if (a.Length > 0)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(downloadFolder + "\\" + exeFolder.Substring(exeFolder.IndexOf('/') + 1) + "\\Launch_Presentation.exe");

            myProcess.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process process = Process.Start(myProcess);
            int Exeid = process.Id;

            this.Visible = false;
            this.Visible = true;
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            pdfFrame.Visible = videoFrame.Visible = false;
            Response.Redirect(Convert.ToString(this.Page.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri));
            process.Exited += (myProcess_HasExited);
        }

        res.Flush();
        res.End();
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

why is it not downloading at client location?

Comment: check client machine read/write permission

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj If I run the code locally with visual studio, it works fine, only when I deploy it somewhere else and try to access the application through URL it downloads on the server machine and runs there itself. I checked the permissions too, It's fine.

Comment: pal .try to log the execution,you will get the idea.

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj there is no error when logged, it downloads and runs the content on server but not client. Am I missing something in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the problem related to permission of the client side Path that defined as downloadFolder. Please check and inform me.